# Add resource path segment for java packages in JAX-RS/Jersey?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm using Jersey 2.19. I would like to support two versions of my API. For that, I would like to have two main paths: `/api/v1` and `/api/v2`. I would like to have two packages `com.test.v1` (with v1 API resources) and `com.test.v2` (with v2 API resources).

I know how to define a path for the whole application, I will just use the `@ApplicationPath('api')` on my `ResourceConfig` class. However, how would I define that package `com.test.v1` resources live in the `/v1` namespace, and package `com.test.v2` resources live in the `/v2` namespace? Currently, I see no other option than to add the 'v1' and 'v2' prefixes in each `@Path` annotation, like: `@Path('v1/something')` or `@Path('v2/something')` prefix to each resource. This is a lot of redundancy.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a proof-of-concept for one way to accomplish this. I have never used this, so I can't really provide any testimony to any maintainability issues that may or or may not come down the line for larger projects. I just tested on a simple project.

It basically uses Jersey's [Programmatic resource building API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html) to append the version to the original path.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Configuration;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelProcessor;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceModel;

@Provider
public class VersioningModelProcessor implements ModelProcessor {

    private Map<String, String> packageAppenders = new HashMap<>();

    {
        packageAppenders.put("com.stackoverflow.jersey.v1", "v1");
        packageAppenders.put("com.stackoverflow.jersey.v2", "v2");
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceModel processResourceModel(ResourceModel model, Configuration config) {

        // Create new resourc model.
        ResourceModel.Builder newModelBuilder = new ResourceModel.Builder(false);
        for (final Resource resource: model.getResources()) {

            // Look for the package
            String path = resource.getPath();
            Class handlerClass = resource.getHandlerClasses().iterator().next();
            String pkg = handlerClass.getPackage().getName();

            // Match the packge to our map of packages
            if (packageAppenders.containsKey(pkg)) {

                // append the version
                String version = packageAppenders.get(pkg);
                path = version + "/" + path.replace("/", "");

                Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder(resource);
                resourceBuilder.path(path);

                Resource newResource = resourceBuilder.build();
                System.out.println(newResource.toString());

                // add the new resource with the new path.
                newModelBuilder.addResource(newResource);
            } else {
                // Do nothing. Just add the resource as normal
                newModelBuilder.addResource(resource);
            }
        }
        return newModelBuilder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceModel processSubResource(ResourceModel model, Configuration config) {
        return model;
    }
}
```

Might be more trouble than it's worth. I don't know. You can be the judge.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it answers my original question. I eventually took a different path, please see my answer.

Comment: @wujek Yes I completely forgot about doing that. I would go ahead and accept your own answer. It makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

In the end I decided to just configure and deploy 2 Jersey servlets. V1 of the API is in module_v1, V2 in module_v2, and I have two servlets with 2 ResourceConfig. The first resource config defines the path 'v1', the second 'v2', and they are both relative to the root of 'api'. This works quite well and allows for simple deletion of any of the versions.